# Auto update flutter application with membership details

Tags: flutter, mobile-development, flutter-http

I am new to mobile development. I am developing a flutter application which has a web version. Users have memberships in that application. When ever a user cancels or activates a membership through web, I want that information to be updated in mobile application. What is the best way to achieve this?

I thought of making API call when profile page is visited, but other pages shall not updated based on memberships. Making an auto-refresh call can be done but won't that be an extra overhead?

Edit: Backend is a wordpress site and whole data for mobile app is done through API calls.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a cloud database, like [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), and construct a `User` class with the data of your database.

Then you display different widgets or screen depending of your `User` class properties.
You should probably also start digging into state management with Flutter for updating the screens if you user cancel/renew his subscription

Comment: Backend is a wordpress site and mobile app gets all it's data by API calls.